# Content-Security-Policy for styles with React and Material-UI v4

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, content-security-policy

There is a React UI that uses material-ui version 4. In Production the web server is embedded into a JVM application. The UI is built with npm and then the bundle is deployed along with the server side code.

The requirement is for the application to use Content-Security-Policy. It is acceptable to use a nonce with a static value in it. I was able to accomplish this by setting the header in the server code and by following directions I found on Material UI site: https://v4.mui.com/styles/advanced/#how-does-one-implement-csp.

Basically I included a nonce in the meta tag in index.html like so:

`<html><head><meta property="csp-nonce" content="mynoncevalue" />`

and on the server side I send the following CSP:

`"default-src 'self' https://mywebserver.mydomain.com;script-src 'self' https://mywebserver.mydomain.com;style-src 'self' 'nonce-mynoncevalue';"`

The UI renders, but there is one problem. The following error appears in the console:

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-mynoncevalue'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash (...), or a nince ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

When I click on "Issues" button and look at "1 page error" and click on the "Element" icon (the one having tooltip "Click to reveal the violating DOM node in the Elements panel"), what appears in the "Elements" panel looks like my index.html with a bunch of tags added inside . The following element appears highlighted:

`<style id="muiDetectElementResize" type="text/css">(...)</style>`

Interestingly, above that element there are a bunch of style elements that looks like the following:

`<style data-jss data-meta-"Mui(Something)" nonce>(...)</style>`

Can anybody suggest where the offending "style" tag (with id="muiDetectElementResize") could be coming from and how is it possible to include the nonce in the same manner as "data-jss" tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is due to a specific style tag being generated by Material-UI without the nonce attribute you've provided. The error is specifically pointing out the  tag, which is used by Material-UI for handling element resize detection.

**Identify the Source of the Element:**

This style element () is likely coming from a component or utility within Material-UI that's responsible for detecting changes in the size of an element. If you're using components like TextareaAutosize or any other component that responds to changes in size, they might be using this utility under the hood.

**Monkey Patching at Runtime:**

As a workaround, you could add a script that runs immediately after your page loads and looks for this style tag. If it finds it, it can add the nonce attribute:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const styleElement = document.getElementById("muiDetectElementResize");
  if (styleElement) {
    styleElement.setAttribute("nonce", "mynoncevalue");
  }
});
```

This is also a hacky solution, but it doesn't involve modifying the Material-UI source code.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Not sure why someone downvoted it. I haven't tested the solution suggested by @Ramon Suarez yet, but this workaround is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding **"unsafe-inline"** in your CSP configuration. Because the styles of components from Mui package is being inlined in order to render it in browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the requirement explicitly states that "unsafe-inline" is unacceptable.

Comment: Then you have to handle it at application level as represented in the documentation itself.  https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/content-security-policy/